# Sensor to detect collision or intervention

Tags: proximity-sensor, robotics, capacitive

I am currently working on a project (robotic arm) where I need to detect human collision with the robot. I need a sensor that should be flexible, detect human intervention in the workspace of the robot and I want to keep a sensor on the surface of the robot. Can someone suggest a commercially available sensor or a sensor that is easily made?

Comment: You can use a lidar scanner, expensive. Or few beam  obstacle sensors.

Comment: how will the robot know it is a human? sounds like you might need a neural net processor like the Terminator T800 series. You'll also require a text to speech app to say 'Get out".

Comment: They may still be using them as crash sensors in cars. We called them roll-a-mite, not sure of the proper name but they had many different varieties. You might also look at impact sensors.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, if your motor controllers have current sensor with better resolution, you can plot the current data and see the variations in current value when obstacle is introduced in the roboric arm trajectory.
Also for more precise control, torque sensors at each robotic arm joints can be integrated to detect the reactive force/obstacle during motion in specified trajectory.

Comment: Current sense sounds like a good fit here; you should be able to predict how hard each motor should be working at any time.